# Removing distorted edges of TIN surface?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, tin

I'm trying to remove the stretched edges of a TIN surface without having to draw a polygon around the features that I want clipped.

Does anyone know how to do this without free hand drawing?

I was thinking an edge detection method could work.

Here's an example:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I think you are looking for the [Delineate TIN Data Area](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q900000087000000) tool:

> Redefines the data area, or interpolation zone, of a triangulated
>   irregular network (TIN) based on its triangle edge length.
>
> [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

If the result you get from [@blah238's correct answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/92298/115) is not acceptable (in my case I can never achieve perfect results using this tool as it is based on triangle edge length) you can digitize a polygon delineating the desired outer extent manually.  Once complete re-create the TIN and add the polygon to the input list (last in hierarchy) and set the SF_Type to hard clip.  In previous versions of ArcGIS the "Hardclip" function sometimes failed so I would run it by itself (Using the Edit TIN tool) on the finished TIN.

If you list the inputs you are using to create this TIN, perhaps there is some data that will allow you to create the "delineation" polygon without having to digitize it.  (Although in many cases it takes less time to digitize than to figure out a way how to create spatial data dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Use the TIN Edge tool (I'm assuming you have 3D Analyst) to extract the triangles as features. Delete the erroneous triangles and then dissolve to get a bounding polygon of the valid elevation values of your surface. Then regenerate your TIN, incorporating that polygon as an exterior boundary.