# Removing pixels in raster map using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

[image]I made a raster. I wonder how can I remove pixels with values lesser than an specific value? for example How is possible to set the value of classes from 0.92?

i have searched it and i found [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/93680/115) to [Removing pixel values below 0 in Digital Elevation Model in ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93675/removing-pixel-values-below-0-in-digital-elevation-model-in-arcgis-for-desktop):

> You can use tool Raster Calculator. Then type this expression:
>
> ```
> SetNull("raster_name"<0.92, "raster_name")
> ```

should i type the "SetNull" in the command? 
i am really confused....

Answer (score 1):

Go to `ArcToolbox -> Spatial Analyst Tools -> Map Algebra -> Raster Calculator`

In the raster calculator, you can either write SetNull("raster_name"<0.92, "raster_name"). Or Double click SetNull from the menu under Conditional menu, then double click the raster layer from raster layer listed in the Table of content from inside raster calculator and add the above expression, as you can see below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much dear @ahmadhanb i am using of Arc GIS 9.2. this is why i cant find setnull is raster calculator. isnt it?

Comment: Then write SetNull if you don't have an option to select from the conditional menu, and change the double quotation " " to square brackets [ ]. You can refer to this article http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000010059

Comment: As you said i changed it but i faced to error again. i typed this: SetNull([runoff105]<0.92, [runoff105])

Comment: Sorry to trouble you @ahmadhanb

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of the raster calculator?

Comment: sure. but how can i load my screenshot? i cant find an option to do that.@ahmadhanb

Comment: Edit you question and click on the icon with mountain shape, then a window will popup. Drag and drop your image into that window and click OK

Comment: i loaded the screenshot.@ahmadhanb

Comment: no i want to setnull for a value less than 0.92 not zero.you know in this map i have some pixel with value 0 to 0.92 and they are not correct this is why i need to eliminate them.

Comment: am i wrong @ahmadhanb

Comment: Try to use setnull([runoff105]<0.92, [runoff105]) instead of SetNull.

Comment: I didn't get your mean. i think because of that i am not fluent in English. it doesn't work. anyway i am so thankful for consuming your time to answer me @ahmadhanb